# Can not apply calculation to all rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `Staff` table in SQL Server with a `Salary` column, and my goal is to calculate the monthly amount and then display it. I figured out 2 ways to do this task but the second one does not work.

Here is my code:

1st method

```
SELECT 
    FirstName, FamilyName, 
    CAST(Salary / 12 AS DECIMAL(8,2)) AS AnnualSalary 
FROM  
    [dbo].[Staff]
```

2nd method

```
DECLARE @monthlySalary DECIMAL(8,2)

SELECT @monthlySalary = CAST(Salary / 12 AS DECIMAL(8, 2)) 
FROM [dbo].[Staff]

SELECT @monthlySalary AS MonthlySalary  
FROM [dbo].[Staff]
```

In the 2nd method it only calculate the 1st salary in the Staff table and then duplicate the result in other rows. Can you help me to find the way to apply the calculation to all the row in Table?

Expected result

[image: Expected result]

Error

[image: Error]

Staff table

[image: Staff table]

Comment: Side note: Wouldn't *dividing* `Salary` by `12` rather be the *MonthlySalary* calculated from the annual salary? Please add sample data and the expected results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Cause

`@annualSalary` has a fixed value **It is not a function**

This line will assign one value to the variable:

```
SELECT @annualSalary  = CAST(Salary/12 as DECIMAL(8,2)) 
FROM [dbo].[Staff]
```

In the second command you are selecting a fixed value which is assigned to `@annualSalary` variable and it is repeated for each row in the Select query

```
SELECT @annualSalary AS AnnualSalary  
FROM [dbo].[Staff]
```

**More information at**

- [SELECT Into Variable When Multiple Rows Returned - SQL Server](http://www.sqlines.com/articles/sql-server/select_into_when_multiple_rows)

---

### Suggestions

If the goal is to calculate the average of all salaries you should use

```
SELECT AVG(CAST(Salary / 12 AS DECIMAL(8, 2)))  
FROM [dbo].[Staff]
```

Else you should use

```
SELECT CAST(Salary / 12 AS DECIMAL(8, 2)) 
FROM [dbo].[Staff]
```

Comment: Thank you i am now understand what is wrong with my second method. I think my first method is the easiest way to this task.

Answer (score 0):

Your second method is declaring a variable of type decimal, which can only store one number at a time.
Therefore, when you are executing the first query, the variable stores one number as its value (which I assume it is the first salary value as you mention) and then when executing the second query you are returning the same value the number of records that are in the staff table.
If you want to store all values of a salary then you may have to use a cursor...but then the query will be the same as in your first example.
Something like

```
DECLARE staff_cursor CURSOR  
    FOR SELECT FirstName, FamilyName, cast(Salary/12 as DECIMAL(8,2)) as AnnualSalary FROM  [dbo].[Staff]
OPEN staff_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM staff_cursor;
```

Comment: I checked your method and it work but only return 1 staff. I've just updated some picture can you check it out.

Comment: Why a cursor for this simple query?

Comment: I was just mentioning a way to save the rows to a variable (a cursor in this case).